How do we know that even doimem is being recreated from the words inside of them every instant?
B"H
In the beginning of shar hayichud vihaemunah in the name of the Baal Shem Tov, it says a teaching (found also with slight variations on midrash tehillim on the verse) on the passuk "forever Hashem Your Word stands in the heavens" (tehillim 119), that the "word" that He spoke at the six days of creation to create the heavens, from nothing, initially,
"Let there be a sky in the waters to separate between water and water",
Is found (stands) inside the heavens constantly (because "His words are eternal"..), constantly creating the heavens from nothing.
It would seem like this initial teaching is already based on implications from the midrash.
But then it goes on to say a new idea, that even in doimem, inorganic matter, like rocks, and this physical earth, is also being recreated every instant from the words that He spoke at the beginning of creation that created those objects
(And even the names of objects which aren't mentioned explicitly can be derived through atbash etc.)
The question is how does the Baal Shem Tov make the connection from the midrash , that His words are inside of the heavens and constantly creating them, to the physical earth?
It doesn't explicitly mention there how it's derived, it just says it is
I was thinking it must be through one of the 13 principals of how the Torah is expounded, but I can't comprehend which one, if any.
It can't be kal vachomer because it would be more logical to say the spiritual world, heavens, which is "closer" to it's source, is being recreated from the words found inside them. But the physical earth? How do we know that?
Words of the midrash:

נאמר לעולם ה' דברך נצב בשמים. מהו דברך נצב בשמים אי זהו דבר הנצב
בשמים. אלא אמר הקב"ה על מה השמים עומדים על אותו דבר שאמרתי (בראשית א
ו-ז) יהי רקיע בתוך המים. ויהי כן. וכתיב (תהלים לג ט) כי הוא אמר ויהי
וגו'. אותו הדבר שאמר הוא עשה. לכך נאמר (שם) הוא צוה ויעמוד. בדבר ה'
שמים נעשו ובאותו הדבר שברא אותן בו הם עומדים לעולם. לכך נאמר לעולם ה'
דברך נצב בשמים.

Words of the Tanya:

וּפִירֵשׁ הַבַּעַל־שֵׁם־טוֹב זִכְרוֹנוֹ לִבְרָכָה:
כִּי "דְּבָרְךָ" שֶׁאָמַרְתָּ "יְהִי רָקִיעַ בְּתוֹךְ הַמָּיִם וְגוֹ'"
–
תֵּיבוֹת וְאוֹתִיּוֹת אֵלּוּ, הֵן נִצָּבוֹת וְעוֹמְדוֹת לְעוֹלָם
בְּתוֹךְ רְקִיעַ הַשָּׁמַיִם,
וּמְלוּבָּשׁוֹת בְּתוֹךְ כָּל הָרְקִיעִים לְעוֹלָם לְהַחֲיוֹתָם,
כְּדִכְתִיב: "וּדְבַר אֱלֹהֵינוּ יָקוּם לְעוֹלָם",
"וּדְבָרָיו חָיִים וְקַיָּימִים לָעַד כוּ'",
כִּי אִילּוּ הָיוּ הָאוֹתִיּוֹת מִסְתַּלְּקוֹת כְּרֶגַע חַס וְשָׁלוֹם
וְחוֹזְרוֹת לִמְקוֹרָן,
הָיוּ כָּל הַשָּׁמַיִם אַיִן וָאֶפֶס מַמָּשׁ, וְהָיוּ כְּלֹא הָיוּ
כְּלָל,
וּכְמוֹ קוֹדֶם מַאֲמַר "יְהִי רָקִיעַ כוּ'" מַמָּשׁ.
וְכֵן בְּכָל הַבְּרוּאִים שֶׁבְּכָל הָעוֹלָמוֹת עֶלְיוֹנִים
וְתַחְתּוֹנִים,
וַאֲפִילוּ אֶרֶץ הַלֵּזוּ הַגַּשְׁמִית וּבְחִינַת דּוֹמֵם מַמָּשׁ,
אִילּוּ הָיוּ מִסְתַּלְּקוֹת מִמֶּנָּה כְּרֶגַע חַס וְשָׁלוֹם
הָאוֹתִיּוֹת מֵעֲשָׂרָה מַאֲמָרוֹת שֶׁבָּהֶן נִבְרֵאת הָאָרֶץ
בְּשֵׁשֶׁת יְמֵי בְרֵאשִׁית,
הָיְתָה חוֹזֶרֶת לְאַיִן וָאֶפֶס מַמָּשׁ, כְּמוֹ לִפְנֵי שֵׁשֶׁת יְמֵי
בְרֵאשִׁית מַמָּשׁ.
וְזֶהוּ שֶׁאָמַר הָאֲרִ"י זִכְרוֹנוֹ לִבְרָכָה, שֶׁגַּם בְּדוֹמֵם
מַמָּשׁ, כְּמוֹ אֲבָנִים וְעָפָר וּמַיִם, יֵשׁ בְּחִינַת נֶפֶשׁ
וְחַיּוּת רוּחָנִית.
דְּהַיְינוּ, בְּחִינַת הִתְלַבְּשׁוּת אוֹתִיּוֹת הַדִּבּוּר מֵעֲשָׂרָה
מַאֲמָרוֹת הַמְחַיּוֹת וּמְהַוּוֹת אֶת הַדּוֹמֵם,
לִהְיוֹת יֵשׁ מֵאַיִן וָאֶפֶס שֶׁלִּפְנֵי שֵׁשֶׁת יְמֵי בְרֵאשִׁית.
וְאַף שֶׁלֹּא הוּזְכַּר שֵׁם "אֶבֶן" בַּעֲשָׂרָה מַאֲמָרוֹת
שֶׁבַּתּוֹרָה,
אַף־עַל־פִּי־כֵן, נִמְשָׁךְ חַיּוּת לָאֶבֶן עַל יְדֵי צֵירוּפִים
וְחִילּוּפֵי אוֹתִיּוֹת,
הַמִּתְגַּלְגְּלוֹת בְּרל"א שְׁעָרִים פָּנִים וְאָחוֹר, כְּמוֹ
שֶׁכָּתוּב בְּסֵפֶר יְצִירָה,
עַד שֶׁמִּשְׁתַּלְשֵׁל מֵעֲשָׂרָה מַאֲמָרוֹת וְנִמְשָׁךְ מֵהֶן צֵירוּף
שֵׁם "אֶבֶן",
וְהוּא חַיּוּתוֹ שֶׁל הָאֶבֶן.
וְכֵן בְּכָל הַנִּבְרָאִים שֶׁבָּעוֹלָם,
הַשֵּׁמוֹת שֶׁנִּקְרָאִים בָּהֶם בִּלְשׁוֹן הַקֹּדֶשׁ – הֵן הֵן
אוֹתִיּוֹת הַדִּבּוּר, הַמִּשְׁתַּלְשְׁלוֹת מִמַּדְרֵגָה לְמַדְרֵגָה
מֵעֲשָׂרָה מַאֲמָרוֹת שֶׁבַּתּוֹרָה,
עַל יְדֵי חִילּוּפִים וּתְמוּרוֹת הָאוֹתִיּוֹת בְּרל"א שְׁעָרִים, עַד
שֶׁמַּגִּיעוֹת וּמִתְלַבְּשׁוֹת בְּאוֹתוֹ נִבְרָא לְהַחֲיוֹתוֹ.
לְפִי שֶׁאֵין פְּרָטֵי הַנִּבְרָאִים יְכוֹלִים לְקַבֵּל חַיּוּתָם
מֵעֲשָׂרָה מַאֲמָרוֹת עַצְמָן שֶׁבַּתּוֹרָה,
שֶׁהַחַיּוּת הַנִּמְשָׁךְ מֵהֶן עַצְמָן – גָּדוֹל מְאֹד מִבְּחִינַת
הַנִּבְרָאִים פְּרָטִיִּים,
וְאֵין כֹּחַ בָּהֶם לְקַבֵּל הַחַיּוּת, אֶלָּא עַל יְדֵי שֶׁיּוֹרֵד
הַחַיּוּת וּמִשְׁתַּלְשֵׁל מִמַּדְרֵגָה לְמַדְרֵגָה פְּחוּתָה
מִמֶּנָּה, עַל יְדֵי חִילּוּפִים וּתְמוּרוֹת הָאוֹתִיּוֹת,
וְגִימַטְרִיָּאוֹת שֶׁהֵן חֶשְׁבּוֹן הָאוֹתִיּוֹת,
עַד שֶׁיּוּכַל לְהִתְצַמְצֵם וּלְהִתְלַבֵּשׁ וּלְהִתְהַוּוֹת מִמֶּנּוּ
נִבְרָא פְּרָטִי.
וְזֶה שְׁמוֹ אֲשֶׁר יִקְרְאוּ לוֹ בִּלְשׁוֹן הַקֹּדֶשׁ, הוּא כְּלִי
לַחַיּוּת הַמְצוּמְצָם בְּאוֹתִיּוֹת שֵׁם זֶה,
שֶׁנִּשְׁתַּלְשֵׁל מֵעֲשָׂרָה מַאֲמָרוֹת שֶׁבַּתּוֹרָה, שֶׁיֵּשׁ
בָּהֶם כֹּחַ וְחַיּוּת לִבְרוֹא יֵשׁ מֵאַיִן, וּלְהַחֲיוֹתוֹ לְעוֹלָם,
דְּ"אוֹרַיְיתָא וְקוּדְשָׁא בְּרִיךְ הוּא כּוּלָּא חַד"


כי לא על־הלחם לבדו יחיה האדם כי על־כל־מוצא פי־יהוה יחיה האדם

Which midrash are you referring to?

@shmosel added .

@RabbiKaii while that verse is often referenced in other places to refer to sparks of tohu, it's not mentioned in this chapter. Also it doesn't seem like the sparks of tohu are actually recreating the bread from nothing, they are just the soul of the bread. References added

The sky is domem.

According to the Baal Shem Tov in כתר שם טוב א קנ״ט, this is a teaching of the Arizal in Likkutei Torah, based on the Midrash where the 10 Statements of Creation are mentioned. The derivation from heavens to all of creation is that, that's what a statement is: it is the life force and entire existence of what it was spoken to create, including inorganic matter.

ותירץ האריז"ל... דארז"ל בעשרה מאמרות נברא העולם פי' ע"י המאמרות עצמן נתהוה הכל דמאמרו של הקב"ה הוא מרום וקדוש ותיכף כשאמר הקב"ה יהי רקיע נתהוה הרקיע כמ"ש בדבר ה' שמים נעשו ונכנס המאמר ההוא בחיות פנימי להחיות הרקיע כל ימות עולם שיעמוד כמ"ש לעולם ה' דברך נצב בשמים. וכן כשאמר תוצא הארץ נפש חיה או תוצא הארץ דשא ועץ פרי אותו המאמר היה מהוה הכל והמאמר הזה הוא חיות פנימי להם
The Arizal answered that... our Sages of blessed memory said "the world was created with ten statements" (Bereishit Rabba 17:1*), meaning everything came into being by the very statements of the Holy One, which are exalted and holy. Immediately when Hashem said "let there be a firmament", the firmament came into being, as it is written "By the statement of Hashem, the heavens were made" (Tehillim 33:6). I.e. the word makes the firmament, and enters it as its internal life force, standing it for all days, as it is written "Forever, Hashem Your Word stands firm in the heavens" (Tehillim 119). So too, as it is written "Let the Earth bring forth living creatures", or "let the earth sprout trees, grass and fruit trees", these statements brought everything into existence and were also the internal life for them.

Shaar HaYichud VehaEmunah discusses this idea further in chapter 3, discussing Hashem's "breath" so to speak, and you can read more about that in Alshich on Shir HaShirim 1:2. There are many sources on this idea.

The Besht gives another example of this from the Pasuk in Devarim 8:3:

כי לא על־הלחם לבדו יחיה האדם כי על־כל־מוצא פי־יהוה יחיה האדם
...for man does not live on bread alone, rather man lives on all that proceed from the mouth of Hashem.

The Besht proceeds to explain why saying a bracha with kavana before eating is what sustains us, because then we draw out the inner life of what we consume.
* see also Bamidbar Rabba 14:1 and this interesting looking page I found going through the Sfas Emes on this.

Amazing, I never knew a different version of the shaar hayichud vihaemunah teaching was in keser Shem Tov. Interesting, though, that only the Tanya mentions the idea that even creations not mentioned in the 10 statements are still created from them, through atbash etc.

I would also be interested in seeing the original source of the arizal on that subject, if it exists in eitz chaim etc.. And why does the Tanya attribute it to the Baal Shem Tov if it's really sourced in the arizal?

@Coreofreality
The Besht states it is in the Ari's Likkutei Torah, I would imagine on Acharei or perhaps Eikev but I leave it to you if you learn Kitvei Ari with someone. The Alter Rebbe is likely specifically quoting the Besht because it is the Besht's specific explanation he is referencing, and he does make a note there that the teaching stems from the Midrash originally, so I don't see it as a big issue.
